# How can I start a DispatcherTimer when my custom control is loaded?

Tags: c#, wpf, abstract-class

I need to be able start a timer when my custom control is loaded. However, I need to be able to do this in the abstract class that all controls of this type inherit from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control does have a `Loaded` event that you can attach to in your abstract base class in order to start the timer.

```
// in ctor of abstract control
_timer = new DispatcherTimer(...);
Loaded += (s,e) => _timer.Start();
```

Comment: Isn't it true that constructors are not inherited?

Comment: Not inherited but still called when constructed via a derived type

Comment: Thank you! I wasted quite a bit of time on this simple misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's your issue is? There are three timers available in .NET and you should be probably able use any of them. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx#S1) article to understand choices and differences between them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a control as abstract one. Like below?
Try the following:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MyControl mycontrol;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //// Your logics...

        mycontrol.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                 /// Try invoking timer here...
            }));
    } 
}

public abstract class MyControl: Control
{

}
```

HTH